# Secured connection between processes in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, connection, communication, process

I'm new to C# and also to Stackoverflow.com :)

I have 2 Projects in my solution in VS2010, the first one is the Parent: Main Application built on C# WPF. and the other one is the Child: Built on C# WinForm.
These two applications going to run on the same computer(Thank you Vignesh Natraj for helping me refine the question).

I'm looking for the best way to communicate between the two, there are 2 features that really important for my application:

1. Fast Communication.
   Reason: their will going to be a massive data and high frequency between those. (Something like 1 to 100 "data-quotes" of string/bool/int for 1 second)
2. Highly secured. 
   2 Reasons:

   a. if some hacker can get this data somehow, my application will be cracked.

   b. If some hacker can block the communication between the 2 processes- my application will also be cracked.

I was looking in Google and found many ways such: SOAP/Anonymous Pipes/WCF... and more... but I really know only the names :) and I don't know where to start...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx) for this which are pretty fast.

For security, you can encrypt the data before sending it, using any of the built-in encryption algorithms available in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Are these two applications going to run on the same computer ? if not, the same network ? do you want it to work over internet ?
In terms of scalability I would suggest you research on WCF as it gives you a variety of options
and in future you can just change the bindings in the config files and support different environments.
WCF supports Named-Pipes, MSMQ, secure http bindings with both message and transport security.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer, these two apps are going to run at the same computer. But in the future I'll need for communicate over the internet, so I'll start with NamedPipes because it seems very easy to start, then WCF... thanks!